# Create a phonegap application with dynamic content and automatic update

Tags: cordova, jsf, mobile, dynamic

I maintain a web application that uses JSF as back-end. We are planning to use AngularJS with a REST server in the next step.

We'd like to export the application as a mobile application using Phonegap. As I understand it, it will only redirect to the online application. But we also need to have an offline application - with frequent update of the content.

Is there a technology that let me export a dynamic application to a mobile (and multi-devices) application and manage update of the content?

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally have the content locally on your app where possible (content being the JS/CSS/HTML etc to render the app and the app logic itself).  You can update this and change it using something like the content sync plugin [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync). For actual "content" as in articles, menu list items, blocks of text you may want to combine this approach (for updating app logic, styles, embedded images etc) with a CMS that has a REST JSON API for dynamic content such as stories, data feeds and so on.

Comment: This is very limited, if the connection id down then actual content cannot be loaded. In my case, I have a search function so it must be performed by the server, no way to do it only within Phonegap...